# In Powershell, how do I print out the data from a custom folder of Outlook(same-level as Inbox)?

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script :

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$sentMail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6) # == olFolderSentMail
$sentMail.folders.item("FDA UFMS User Provision").Items |  %{ $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject ,"Request\s\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} | %{$Result=[regex]::Match($_,"\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} |
Out-File C:\Temp\Powershell_6_digit_Codes.txt -Append
```

However, it does not grab the data from the `FDA UFMS User Provision` folder, as it is on the same level as Inbox(not within Inbox).

How can I change my script of     `$sentMail.folders.item("FDA UFMS User Provision").Items` so that it gets this data?

so far I tried

`$sentMail.item("FDA UFMS User Provision").Items`

but that didn't yield correct result.

[image]

thanks !

Comment: if you expand your inbox just below where the yellow line is covering is that FDA UFMS a sub folder to that? Since its in your Favorites view its hard to tell how you would actually navigate to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application

$sentMail = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6) # == olFolderSentMail

$bigFolder = $sentMail.Parent


$ufms = "FDA UFMS User Provision"


$newufms = $bigFolder.folders.item($ufms)


$newufms.Items | %{ $RESULT=[Regex]::Match($_.TaskSubject, "Request\s\d{6}"); if ($RESULT.Success)

{$RESULT.Value}} | %{$Result=[Regex]::Match($_, "\d{6}"); if($RESULT.Success){$RESULT.Value}} | Out-File C:\Temp

\Powershell_6_digit_Codes.txt -Append
```